# using value of void function in java

Tags: java, matlab

```
import matlabcontrol.*;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws MatlabConnectionException, MatlabInvocationException {
        // create proxy
        MatlabProxyFactoryOptions options =
                new MatlabProxyFactoryOptions.Builder()
                        .setUsePreviouslyControlledSession(true)
                        .build();
        MatlabProxyFactory factory = new MatlabProxyFactory(options);
        MatlabProxy proxy = factory.getProxy();


        // call builtin function
        proxy.eval("disp('hello world1')");
        proxy.eval("addpath('E:\\Karshenasi Arsha\\term 4 (payan name)\\payan name\\Matlab')");

        //my problem is here
        proxy.feval("CalculatinScore", 0.4, 0.1, 0.8, 0.5);
        proxy.eval("rmpath('E:\\Karshenasi Arsha\\term 4 (payan name)\\payan name\\Matlab')");


        // close connection
        proxy.disconnect();
    }
}
```

in this code, i'm trying to call a method from matlab(CalculatinScore) and using the result.
but feval() is void, and doesn't return value.
how i can use the result?
for example in C# you can use this :

matlab.Feval("GetParameters", 1, out result, individual[0] / 60, individual[2], individual[1]);
        object[] res = result as object[];

and use the result of void method
what can i do in java?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [javadocs](http://diffplug.github.io/matconsolectl/javadoc/snapshot/matlabcontrol/MatlabProxy.html) for `MatlabProxy`, there is a method called `returningFeval` that returns the matlab function-call results in an `Object[]`.  Something like this:

```
Object[] res = proxy.returningFeval("CalculatinScore", 1, /* one result */
                                     0.4,0.1,0.8,0.5 );
```

For the record, you cannot use the result of `void` method because a `void` method does not return any result.

Comment: thanks for your answer. can i print the answer. for example here answer is 0.5. i tried to print it with ToString() method but i got [D@4fca772d

Comment: That is telling you that the result you are actually getting is an array of `double`.  Cast it, and took at the first element.